# How do you obtain the content of a specific node using XmlDocument in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I have an XML file that looks like:

```
<root>
    <song id="1">
        <name> A Whole New World </name>
        <artist> Lea Salonga </artist>
    </song>
    <song id="2">
        <name> Colors of the Wind </name>
        <artist> Judy Kuhn </artist>
    </song>
    <song id="3">
        <name> Reflection </name>
        <artist> Lea Salonga </artist>
    </song>
    <song id="4">
        <name> Part of Your World </name>
        <artist> Sierra Boggess </artist>
    </song>
</root>
```

And I want to parse this XML file with C#. I know that I should use `System.Xml.XmlDocument` to parse the XML file. The Microsoft documentation says the square bracket operator `[Name]` returns only "the first child element with the specified `Name`".

So my question here is:
*how do I get, from the example XML file above, the name of the song that has the id 4?*

Comment: XmlDocument is deplorable. Use XDocument instead.

Answer (score 2):

Look at Xpath and use xpath query, you can test it here http://www.xpathtester.com/test

```
//song[@id="4"]/name
```

in c# escape " char with \ like

```
"//song[@id=\"4\"]/name"
```

Comment: You should note that this can be done with the `SelectSingleNode` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to use Xpath queries, you can use the old way:

You can loop over the childnodes, check each child that the element's name is "song", then check the attribute, then get the name. But Xpath would be shorter though.